# Echo Back Text instead of Input field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below but I want it to `echo "Expired"`. Tried a few things but it isn't working.

```
$result["expired_product_message"] = 
             get_post_meta( $post_id, 
                    '_was_expired_product_message', false);//If this is empty

update_post_meta(if isset($result["expired_product_message"])) 
            {echo 'EXPIRED';}//Add "Expired" to the post meta and display
```

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid we'll need a bit more info. You want to echo something, yet there's nowhere in this code where you try and echo a value? Thanks!

Comment: @MacPrawn Maybe something like this would be clearer?

Comment: Hmm, ok, so you don't echo to update meta data, no. Echo is solely to display on screen. Are you trying to update the value of the "_was_expired_product_message" meta field?

Comment: @MacPrawn Currently there is an input box (_was_expired_product_message) on each post that you can add a custom message. I want one static message "Expired" on all the posts. I don't want to enter the same message in every post's input box.

Comment: Ok but so you want to replace the "_was_expired_product_message" value with "Expired" and lose the old value that was in the field? If that's really what you want to do, it would be something like `update_post_meta($post_id, '_was_expired_product_message', (!empty($result["expired_product_message"]) ? 'EXPIRED' : ''))`

Comment: @MacPrawn It's fine to lose the old value. I tried it and a few variations but it isn't displaying "expired". Do I need to do something with `$result["expired_product_message"] = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_was_expired_product_message', true);` I tried false.

Comment: @MacPrawn It is displaying "array"

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
 if(!empty($result["expired_product_message"])) {
    $expired = "EXPIRED";
 }
 else {
    $expired = "";
 }
 update_post_meta($post_id, '_was_expired_product_message', $expired);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your latest comments, I believe this is what you want:

```
$result["expired_product_message"] = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_was_expired_product_message', true);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_was_expired_product_message', ($result["expired_product_message"] ? 'EXPIRED' : ''));
```

Now *$result["expired_product_message"]* will either be null or a string value, depending on if it is defined and filled-out for this particular post. That should display fine.

The second line will update the *same* field and set its value to "EXPIRED" if, and only if, there was a non-empty string in *$result["expired_product_message"]* to begin with.

The next time you *get_post_meta* for that same post_id, (`get_post_meta( $post_id, '_was_expired_product_message', true)`) you should now get "Expired" or "".

Hope this helps!